# Receiving Email Log Package from previous release version of the App

Tags: codenameone

I still receive the codename One device log package related to previous version of the Mobile App which is not in the stores anymore. Does this mean user didn't upgrade the App to latest version or is there anything else going on. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It means there are users that didn't update the app to the latest version. Unfortunately there's not that much you can do about it now. This slightly older [post](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-cross-platform-update-available-strategy.html) covers the strategy you can take to avoid this.

Comment: In Codename One device log package: com. version: 2.7.0. Where is this referring from.  App version and codename log package is same or differeent. Because actual App is 2.8.0 since 1 year and now it is 2.9.0, I was expecting to see log 2.8.0 but not 2.7.0. is it something where I forgot to update the log package in previous release. I don't think any one still using 2.7.0, Please advise.

Comment: People can avoid updating for years